# setting more than eight colors for data series in JavaFX ScatterChart

Tags: java, css, javafx

I'm trying to set the colors of eleven data series in a ScatterChart. Unfortunately JavaFX repeats colors and symbols every eight series due to the nextClearBit which is set to mudulo eight by design. There is a solution to overcome this by setting the colors manually for each data series in CSS like:

```
.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #e9967a; }
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #f0e68c; }
.default-color2.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: #dda0dd; }
```

...and so on.

This works for LineCharts. So I tryed a similar approach for my ScatterChart, but...

```
.default-color0.chart-symbol { -fx-stroke: #e9967a; }
.default-color1.chart-symbol { -fx-stroke: #f0e68c; }
.default-color2.chart-symbol { -fx-stroke: #dda0dd; }
```

...and so on works until...

```
.default-color8.chart-symbol { -fx-stroke: #e9a0dd; }
```

At this point Java ignores my CSS and jumps to the formatting of the first data series following the nextClearBit rule.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `.default-color8` styleclass doesn't exist in `modena.css` so it is pointless to use it.

Comment: No, I didn't say that. JavaFX repeats its color combination after the 8th series. You should use `.series0`, `.series1` etc instead of `.default-color`.

Comment: Check out [Manually Set a Series Style on JavaFX ScatterChart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030563/manually-set-a-series-style-on-javafx-scatterchart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaFX Scatter chart repeats its color combination after the `8th series`. So there is no styleclass `.default-color8` in the JavaFX style css file `modena.css`.

If you want to color your series, you should be depend on the `styleclass` which represents the `series` and not the `color` itself.

Try using `series0`, `.series1`, and so on, as your style class instead of `.default-color0`, `.default-color1` ...